# Way to deal with large data files in Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I wonder if there exists way to work with large files in Mathematica ?
Currently I have a file about 500Mb with table data.

```
Import["data.txt","Table"];
```

What is alternate way?

Comment: it takes too much time to load large file. and I think too much memory too.

Comment: Similar question was asked again here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525782/import-big-files-arrays-with-mathematica . I gave two solutions for dense and sparse tables, which those coming to this page may find useful. They are still rather slow, but much more memory-efficient than `Import`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`OpenRead["file"]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OpenRead.html) which gives you an `InputStream` object on which you can use [`Read[stream]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Read.html). Depending on the formatting of the data file you may need to set custom option values in [`Read[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Read.html) for `RecordSeparators`.

Example:

```
In[1]:= str = OpenRead["ExampleData/USConstitution.txt"]    
Out[1]= InputStream["ExampleData/USConstitution.txt", 24]   

In[2]:= Read[str, Word]    
Out[2]= "We"    
In[3]:= Read[str, Word]
Out[3]= "the"    
In[4]:= Read[str, Record]
Out[4]= "People of the United States, in Order to form a more perfect Union,"
```

Comment: You need to remember to close the stream when you are done.  Also, if you abort the operation, the stream will remain open.  This can result in nasty surprises.  So, I'd recommend wrapping your read code in a `CheckAbort` to catch the abort, and then close the stream regardless of whether the operation has been aborted or not.

Answer (score 5):

You could also load your data into a database (for example MySQL) and access it from Mathematica using [DatabaseLink](http://www.wolfram.com/solutions/databaselink/)

Answer (score 2):

The function `DumpSave` can also be helpful for saving large datasets. It saves data in Mathematica's internal format, so it's more efficient in both time and file size.